# How to unify KDE 4.5 theme when running kde applications with root?

Tags: kde, root, themes

I am using Kubuntu with KDE 4.5.3. When I run KDE applications with root privilage the Theme/UI does not look same/unify with my theme. How to fix it?

Comment: copy the kde theme config into root's home...i'm being horribly inspecific that's why it's a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the root theme/ui permatenly with:

```
$ sudo systemsettings
```

Otherwise you can copy all your kde configuration to root by:

```
$ sudo cp -R ~/.kde* /root/
```

Comment: I don't see this working! I used sudo systemsettings to define bigger fonts. Still when using the user managegement (which is a sudo application of course) I get the small fonts again.
"sudo systemsettings doesN#t work crrectly. With your other solution my problem is, I only want the appearance settings not all application settings... Any better suggestions? thx